# Backup software marking error as success?

Tags: backup, nas, acronis-trueimage

I'm really stumped here.

We got a [Seagate BlackArmor NAS 110](http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/products/network_storage/blackarmor/) device in our small office (3 computers) to do regular backups of our Windows (XP and 7) PCs.

Recently, the device was offline and we *only noticed this by chance* as it seems that the [BlackArmor Backup Software](http://www.seagate.com/ww/v/index.jsp?locale=en-US&name=ba-acronis-win&vgnextoid=973da5c909230210VgnVCM1000001a48090aRCRD) -- which is based on [Acronis True Image](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/) -- *will mark backups that **fail** due to a non available backup drive as **sucess**!*

See this scrennshot: (explanation follows)

[image: Screenshot of Blackarmor Backup marking an error as green-success]

I apologize that it's in german, but it should be easy to understand:

Starting in the week of September 4th, the backup device was offline. Still, all backups were *marked as success* (green) and the logs just show `(1) started / (2) Disk I/O error` and nothing else.

### The question now is

What I'd like to know now either form BlackArmor users (or, more likely, from Acronis "power" users), is, whether:

- my analysis makes sense so far?
- anyone else has ever been hit by this (with BlackArmor or TrueImage)?
- maybe there's an option I have missed and that's the reason we don't get any alarm bells from the software when the backup device is offline?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Seagate for an updated version, or for some ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: @techie007 - The link to the Backup Software still reads v1.00 so I do not assume there's a newer version. My colleague also contacted Seagate support but didn't get any reply. (I'm not surprised. Would've been the first time I'd got any decent support for a "consumer" product.)

Comment: Crappy.  Perhaps a phone call would be more productive?  United States, Canada, Latin America, Mexico -- 1.800.SEAGATE (1.800.732.4283) or 1.405.324.4700 -- 8am - 11:30am CT, 1pm - 6pm CT, Monday - Friday. :) Otherwise I think you're stuck until they fix their software, as it appears they aren't trapping that error properly (if at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't help you with the issue specifically but my advice would be this:

It would take ages to get this sorted via customer support at either Seagate or Acronis. If they haven't released updates to fix this error by now, they are unlikely to do so in the near future, if at all. Return the device and get a completely different one as soon as possible.